# compiling project with jdk1.5 using maven2

Tags: maven-2, compiler-construction, maven-plugin, java

i managed to create my project structure using maven2.
but when am compiling my project using mvn install
getting error
generics are not supported in -source 1.3

googled to build my project using jdk1.5 and added build tag

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
           <artifactId>project</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.5</source>
               <target>1.5</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
     <plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

but this is not working.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the maven-compiler-plugin to your build:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: That's what I am doing, too. But is this really the easiest way? I thought Maven was all about "convention over configuration", but everyone must be using this (unintuitive) setting these days. Will they change the default one day (maybe with Maven 3)?

Answer (score 0):

There's an "easier" way to accomplish this, without having to paste the same snippet all over your modules. You can set up a reactor and then you refer to it from all the other modules, like this:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor</artifactId>    
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
```

In the pom file of your reactor you have to put this:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

To let maven know that it's not a jar/war, etc.

Hope it helps